# Dataset getting manipulated in between two webservice

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, wcf-rest

I have a restful WCF web service and a WCF web service.. the flow is like RestWCF calls the WCF with an id and WCF service hits the database and get the result into a dataset and returns that to RestWCF

The row contains

- id - int
- name - string
- opentime - datetime
- closetime - datetime

In the WCF dataset the row looks fine but when we return the dataset to the RestWCF the timing cells get changed .. I mean the time gets modified... it shows wrong time.. like 4:20 becomes 5:50

Comment: Sounds like a timezone problem - any chance your servers are in different time zones (or are configured with different time zones)??

Comment: Is one server in India? India that has a time zone on the 1/2 hour?

Comment: the server is in US and other is in India.. will the problem will get solved if i upload the other service to US
is it the framework problem.. y is it altering a dataset???

Comment: the dataset is not being altered. It's probably storing the datetime stamp in an ISO format (i.o.w; it containts a GMT+xx offset). When reading the data into a DateTime variable, this is taken into consideration, hence the difference in time you see when reading it.

Comment: @MarvinSmit if I upload both service on same server than it will not give error??

Comment: If they are on the same server, this change should not occur if both applications are using the same "Culture/Timezone". You can actually set this information on a per process basis. You could use Fiddler (or similar tool) to verify what data actually 'crosses the wire'.

Comment: @MarvinSmit that worked.. post ur comment as answer abt the offset thing so that i can select ur annswer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dataset is not being altered. It's probably storing the datetime stamp in an ISO format (i.o.w; it containts a GMT+xx offset). When reading the data into a DateTime variable, this is taken into consideration, hence the difference in time you see when reading it.

If they are on the same server, this change should not occur if both applications are using the same "Culture/Timezone". You can actually set this information on a per process basis. You could use Fiddler (or similar tool) to verify what data actually 'crosses the wire'

Answer by Marvin Smit